# Saving the REDHAWK SDR IDE Chalkboard

Tags: redhawksdr

Is there a way to save the current chalkboard to allow you to reuse it later?  I can perform a Save As, but that saves it as a waveform.  If I don't save it, the chalkboard disappears when I close REDHAWK IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the short answer is no.  There is no way to save an instance of the Chalkboard and reload it into the Chalkboard.

What you may want to do, is save the Chalkboard as a waveform using File->Save As.  Then, you may "Launch a Local Waveform" from the Overview tab of the Waveform Editor.  This will launch the waveform within the Sandbox, essentially making a new Chalkboard instance that you may interact with in the same way as the Chalkboard, including the ability to modify and resave the the current Sandbox instance as a new waveform to repeat the process.

One final thing to keep in mind, the Chalkboard/Sandbox does not set an Assembly Controller so once you are done and want to run this waveform within the Domain, you'll need to designate an Assembly Controller or else you will get an error on launch.